# How to return character entity In Angular2 template?

Tags: javascript, angular

```
@Component({
  selector: 'return-html',
  template: `{{ foo() }}` 
})

foo(){
     return "&#8364;"
  }
```

The code above prints "& #8364;" rather then € symbol. How can I change it to display the "€" character instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There might be other soluations but this should work:

```
template: `<span [innerHTML]="foo()"></span>`
```

Comment: but that means I'm introducing unnecessary span tag for no other purpose then syntax workaround

Comment: Yes, but that's currently the simplest way I know to make Angular add text as HTML instead of literal text.